# How to change itemize bullet to a square

Tags: enumerate, itemize

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt,answers]{exam}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}


%\newbool{annotated}
% \truebool{annotated}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphpap}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\myrule}{\rule[-0.1mm]{1.5in}{0.1mm}}
\newcommand{\longrule}{\myrule\myrule}
\newcommand{\lilrule}{\rule[-0.1mm]{0.5in}{0.1mm}}
\newcommand{\finish}{\hfill\myrule}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.75in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.5in}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\textbf{C++ -- Classes}}

\vspace{0.2in}

\noindent Name: \myrule\myrule

\vspace{0.4in}

% \fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}

% % \textbf{The aims of the algorithm are to: 
% %     \begin{itemize}
% %     \item Know the purpose of the reading
% %     \item Get the most information out of the reading
% %     \item Commit reasonable time to the reading
% %     \item Minimize frustration and stress
% %     \end{itemize}
% % }
% \end{minipage}
% }

\vspace{0.4in}
%
%\noindent \emph{Pledge:On my honor, I have neither received nor given aid on this test.}
%
%\vspace{0.4in}
%
%Signature:\myrule\myrule
%\newpage
\section{Question 1: } 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{\arabic*}]
\item 
\begin{itemize}
\item % I need to get a square bullet
\end{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\vspace{1.5in}
\item Preliminary QUESTIONS:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \longrule 
    \item \longrule 
    \item \longrule 
    \item \longrule
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 3):

using package : `ifsym` option : geometry

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{The first}
  \begin{itemize}[label=\SmallCircle]
  \item Some text here over fifth lines\ldots{} bla blah
  \end{itemize}

\item \textbf{The second}
  \begin{itemize}[label=\FilledSmallSquare]
  \item Other text here over multiple lines\ldots{} bla blablaaah
  \end{itemize}

\item \ldots

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: look on Table 261 page 79 : `\Square` : http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: ifsym does not work on Overleaf.